# Connect my mongo with PHP(filter returned document)

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect to my mongo database, using php code. I am not so sure about what I have tried already. Here is my code:

```
$mongoHostname = ".. . ... . ... . ...";//"localhost";
$databaseName = "db";

$conn = new Mongo('mongodb://'.$mongoHostname.'/'.$databaseName);
// access database
$db = $conn->$databaseName;
// access collection
$collection = $db->coll;

$file = 'names.txt'; //a file with screenames
$data = file($file) or die('Could not read file!');

foreach ($data as $line)
{
  $cursor = $collection->find(array('user.screen_name' => $line));
  print_r($cursor);

}
```

My collection coll in mongo has a field user which contain several element about user one of them is screen_name. How can I show my query object? Am I connect proper my mongo database? How can I check it? I have already install php drivers. The above code works without echo something.

EDIT: Basically I found that I have to use the following command `ini_set('mongo.long_as_object', 1);` I don't know exactly what this command stands about. Finally I manage to return the cursor object which contains all user data. How can I filter that document to extract specific fields, for example user.description and user.location?  I tried to do something like that:

```
foreach ($data as $line)
{
 $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line);
 $cursor = $collection->find(array('user.screen_name' => $line));

 while ($cursor->hasNext()){

    $nextCursor = $cursor->getNext(); 
    $text = (string)$nextCursor["text"];
    echo $text. '<br>';
    //process next cursor
 }

    $descr = (string)$cursor["user"]['description'];
    $location = (string)$cursor["user"]['location'];
    $url = (string)$cursor["user"]['url'];
    $image_url = (string)$cursor["user"]['profile_image_url'];

    echo "user information:   ".$descr.'<br>';
    echo 'user location:    '.$location.'<br>';
    echo "url: ".$url."<br>";
         echo  "<a href=\"" . $temp . "\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\">" . $temp . "</a><br>\n";
 echo "<br><br>";
 }
```

While the first while loop works fine printing the document text fine, outside the while loop I got problems printing rest fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what I did was to iterate every document and not all of them. My code:

```
$temp_url = "https://twitter.com/";
foreach ($data as $line)
{

 $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line);
 $cursor = $collection->find(array('user.screen_name' => $line));

 while ($cursor->hasNext()){

    $nextCursor = $cursor->getNext(); 
    $text = (string)$nextCursor["text"];
    echo $text. '<br>';

    $img = $nextCursor["images"];
    foreach ($img as $image) {
        print_r($image['link']);
        echo "<img src='" . $image['link'] . "' alt='error'>";
        echo '<br>';
    }

    //process next cursor
      foreach($cursor as $document) {  
         echo ($document['user']['description'].'<br>');
         echo ($document['user']['location'].'<br>');
         echo ($document['user']['url'].'<br>');
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How to filter for specific fields:

```
$fields = array('user.description'=>true);
$cursor = $collection->find(array('user.screen_name' => $line),$fields);
```

To use the the results as an array:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
```

please read the official documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Comment: If I use your approach, how can I access description with $array variable. When I var_nump($array) I got the filtered document, however when I tried to do something like $array['user']['description'] I got errors.